# How to describe this UMAP connectivity figure

Tags: feature-engineering, dimensionality-reduction, graphs

I generated this UMAP connectivity diagram of my research data.  How do I interpret/describe this plot regarding the UMAP connectivity?

Is it correct to say that:

1. As there is a lot of connectivity between B8 and B6 that the clusters are similar?
2. Groups B1, B5, B3, B6 and B8 are similar as compared to B0, B4, B7 and B9?

[image]

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The number of lines makes that graph hard to interpret.

It might be easier to understand by reducing the complexity through clustering. Spectral clustering works well for graphs. In particular, spectral clustering can help identify well-connected subgraphs.

Comment: From your comment, do you mean to do spectral clustering then use that data for the UMAP?